# Regex greedy match based on string

Tags: regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

1) I try to match full parts of the string with a regex. There is a problem with the greediness, I think.Below is the structure of pl/sql under consideration

```
ERRORHANDLER
WHEN TRUE THEN
    IF SOMETHING THEN
     ELSE
    END IF;
WHEN FALSE THEN
END;
```

> Following is the regex which I have framed to match **^(\s*)ERRORHANDLER((?!FUNCTION).)*END[(\s*)(\w+)|;]**

Where ,

`^(\s*)ERRORHANDLER`- to match random spaces and static string ERRORHANDLER which will always be the start of the pattern.

`((?!FUNCTION).)*`  - negative look ahead with greedy *

`END[(\s*)(\w+)|;]` - to match END along with optional string ending with semi-colon.

although I am sure of the approach to match the string but this regex is not matching it properly.

**Expected Output:**

complete match for

```
ERRORHANDLER
WHEN TRUE THEN
    IF SOMETHING THEN
     ELSE
    END IF;
WHEN FALSE THEN
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

since here both the start and end are word based , it requires usage of boundary and below 2 are incorporated ,

- starting and ending words.
- between them quantifying with character and meta-character.

so for the question this regex will match \bERRORHANDLER[\w|\W]+END\b;